# android get tab strip on top for bottom tabHost

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a layout for bottom tabs. However, I am not able to set the strip on top of tabHost. How to do it? Thank you.

here my main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"                    
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"

     />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

and also a selector for tab style:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#aa3434"
            android:endColor="#432233"
            android:angle="270"
             />
    </shape>
</item>

 <item android:state_selected="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#aa3434"
            android:endColor="#432233"
            android:angle="270" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```